# Struggling with react states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to build a CV generator web app and I'm having problems with properly setting states so they display correct information. The issue is I can't seem to figure out how to set states so that my CV preview renders correctly, I have tried a of different things with no effect. Any tips or solutions would be welcome.

As for the code here's a hosted
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-mendel-kfhw6l)

Also code incase sandbox goes down:

App.js

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/App.css";
import CV from "./cv/CV";
import Form from "./form/Form";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      Experience: {
        Experience: {
          Workplace: '',
          Position: '',
          ToExp: '',
          FromExp: '',
          AchievementsExp: '',
        }
      },
      Experiences: [
        {Experience: {
         Workplace: '',
         Position: '',
         ToExp: '',
         FromExp: '',
         AchievementsExp: '',
        }},
      ],
    }
  };

  handleChangeExperience = (e) => {
    const key= e.target.name
    const value = e.target.value

    this.setState({
      Experience: {
        Experience: {
          [key]: value,
        },
      },
    });
  };



  handleExperiencePush = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.Experiences.push(this.state.Experience);
    this.setState({
      Experiences: this.state.Experiences
    })
  }

  handleExperiencePop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.Experiences.pop();
    this.setState({
      Experiences: this.state.Experiences
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form 
        handleChangeExperience = {this.handleChangeExperience}
        handleExperiencePush = {this.handleExperiencePush}
        handleExperiencePop = {this.handleExperiencePop}
        handleFormSubmit = {this.handleFormSubmit}
        experiences = {this.state.Experiences}
        />
        <CV 
        experiences = {this.state.Experiences}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

Also for reference, here's how I try to cast each element of Experiences array into a displaying component

Component.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import PersonalCV from "./PersonalCV";


class CV extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div className="CV">
          {this.props.experiences.map((Experience) => {
          return (
            <PersonalCV 
            Experience = {Experience}
            />
          )
        })}
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default CV;
```

Comment: Which objects are you trying to set the state for? Are you looking to store all sections of the CV in a global state?

Comment: Your code should be included in your question. Otherwise if e.g. Codesandbox goes down, the question is worthless for future readers since there's no context.

Comment: I'm trying to set states for Experience objects so that whenever I create new Experience component i also create corresponding object to store the input values in and then display those values in adequate ExperienceCV components.

Comment: It sort of seems like you are doing what you are saying except for the pop function which just removes the last added CV instead of removing CV by ID which is what I think you want to do.

Comment: I think other functions are off too. For example the Push function behaves not the way I want it to if there's a value in one of previous inputs, it just keeps appending last modified input, which I get because I'm pushing the latest state of the object, but I can't figure out how to do it so as soon as I create a in input component I also create a display component that will update live with input of corresponding input component.

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues here.

First, on `setState`, React performs a **shallow merge** of the current state and new state. It *only* merges direct properties of the state object.

Actually I think *merge* is a confusing word to use here, because it suggests React will do more than it actually does. The algorithm is simple:

1. Start with the current state object
2. Example the update object
3. For each key in the update object, if the value at that key is different from the state's value at that key, set the current state object's value at that key to the updated value
4. If any state value was changed, re-render

For clarity, I will change your state shape so each key is unique:

```js
{
  CurrentExperience: {
    Experience: {
      ...
    }
  },
  AllExperiences: [{ Experience: { ... } }]
}
```

Take a look at this:

```js
handleChangeExperience = (e) => {
  const key= e.target.name
  const value = e.target.value

  this.setState({
    CurrentExperience: {
      Experience: {
        [key]: value,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Imagine our current state has:

```js
{
  CurrentExperience: {
    Experience: {
      Workplace: 'MegaCorp',
      Position: 'Senior Developer',
      ToExp: 'today',
      FromExp: '2019',
      AchievementsExp: 'Went to lots of meetings',
    }
  },
  AllExperiences: [...]
}
```

You realize that maybe this isn't the most compelling CV entry, so you use the form to update it, sending an event to `handleChangeExperience`:

```js
{
  target: {
    name: "AchievementsExp",
    value: "Synergized with key stakeholders to empower strategic value-adds"
  }
}
```

Now `handleChangeExperience` calls `setState`:

```js
this.setState({
  CurrentExperience: {
    Experience: {
      AchievementsExp: "Synergized with key stakeholders to empower strategic value-adds"
    }
  }
})
```

According to the algorithm above, what happens?

Start with the current state object:

```js
{
  CurrentExperience: {
    Experience: {
      Workplace: "MegaCorp",
      Position: "Senior Developer",
      ...
    }
  },
  AllExperiences: [...]
}
```

Examine the update object:

```js
{
  CurrentExperience: {
    Experience: {
      AchievementsExp: "Synergized with key stakeholders to enable win-win value-adds"
    }
  }
}
```

For each key in the update object, if the state's value at that key is different from the update's value at that key, set the current state's value at that key to the updated value:

```js
reactInternalState.CurrentExperience = update.CurrentExperience
```

What is the result?

```js
{
  CurrentExperience: {
    Experience: {
      AchievementsExp: "Synergized with key stakeholders to enable win-win value-adds"
    }
  },
  AllExperiences: [ ... ]
}
```

A state value was changed, so we re-render.

But - uh oh, we lost all the rest of the information inside `CurrentExperience.Experience`!

Instead, beyond the immediate children of the state, we need to merge objects ourselves, like this:

```
const oldExperience = state.CurrentExperience.Experience
const newExperience = {
  ...oldExperience,
  [key]: value
}

this.setState({
  CurrentExperience: {
    Experience: newExperience
  }
})
```

---

Second, React always compares props and values of `state` **by reference**, meaning "is this the same object", not "does this object have the same values".

Consider this method:

```js
handleExperiencePush = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.state.AllExperiences.push(this.state.CurrentExperience);
  this.setState({
    AllExperiences: this.state.AllExperiences
  })
}
```

`state.AllExperiences` is an array. Let's call him Bob. Bob has a bag of things.

`this.state.AllExperiences.push(this.state.CurrentExperience)` says "Bob, please put `this.state.CurrentExperience` into your bag." Now Bob's bag has whatever it had before, and also `this.state.CurrentExperience`.

Next we set the state:

```js
this.setState({
  AllExperiences: this.state.CurrentExperiences
})
```

React does the same thing we looked at above - it takes each key in the update object, compares its value to that key's value in the state object, and changes the state if the values are different.

So React looks at the update value, and sees that `AllExperiences` is Bob the Array. Then it looks at the current state, and sees that `AllExperiences` is Bob the Array. Since the two values are equal, no state change is needed. Since there was no state change, React won't re-render the component. (More precisely, React is *not guaranteed* to re-render the component. Whether or not React re-renders is an internal implementation detail. It can re-render whenever it wants to. All we can do is take actions that *guarantee* that there will *eventually* be a re-render with updates.)

So for React to understand that there is an update and re-render, we need to give it a different value - a different array. Like this:

```js
handleExperiencePush = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newExperiences = [
    ...this.state.AllExperiences,
    this.state.CurrentExperience
  ];
  this.setState({
    AllExperiences: newExperiences
  })
}
```

Here, we create a new array. Let's call her Jane.

Then we take all of the items out of Bob's bag, make a new bag, put all the items into it (in the same order), and give the bag to Jane. (Bob's bag is unchanged, though - the physical analogy has limits.) Then we say "Jane, here is `this.state.CurrentExperience`, put it in your bag".

Now we call `setState`. React compares the value at `state.CurrentExperience` to the value at `update.CurrentExperience`, and sees that while the current state has Bob the Array, the update has Jane the Array. Since these are different arrays, React kicks out Bob, puts Jane at `state.CurrentExperience`, and since there was a change, it re-renders. (Again, technically: since there was a change, `App` is now *guaranteed* to *eventually* re-render with the change applied. But React has the right to wait before re-rendering, or to collect several changes and re-render with all of them at once, or whatever React feels like doing.)

**General advice**: whenever you're in a situation where you change the state and it doesn't update as expected, or it seems like updates are delayed or inconsistent across multiple components, first make sure that whenever you update state, state actually gets *new* objects and arrays and never re-uses existing ones.

Comment: I tried to take some time to fully understand your solution. I refactored the code according to your tips but it made zero difference in how the code behaves, while I understand the mistakes I made the functionality stayed the same, working with the same bugs.

Comment: @boobel I forked your sandbox and made some changes to get it working in the way that I think you intend. https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-franklin-l7ztyd

The core problem has to do with how `Form` is implemented. It's... not correct. I added comments to explain what I did and why. Hopefully this helps, let me know if anything needs to be explained more clearly! (And hopefully the StackOverflow gods don't delete this comment...)